# Экспорт таблицы в формат dbf - не экспортируются заголовки полей

Tags: python, python-2.x, dbf

Стоит задача организовать экспорт таблицы из postgresql в формат dbf средствами python. Для реализации я использую пакет dbfpy.

```
from dbfpy import dbf, fields, header

class Serializer(base.Serializer):

def start_serialization(self):
    self.db = dbf.Dbf(self.stream, new=True)
    self.schema = []
    self.dbfh = header.DbfHeader()

def start_object(self, obj):
    if self.first:
        self.names = {}
        # Заполнение схемы данных - тип и название колонок
        for field in obj._meta.fields:
            if ('name' in self.options) and self.options['name']:
                self._name = self.options.pop('name')
                head_name = field.name.upper()[:10]
            else:
                self._name = False
                head_name = field.verbose_name[:10].encode('cp1251').upper()
                if 'name' in self.options:
                    self.options.pop('name')
            self.schema.append((head_name, 'C', 64))
        self.db.addField(*self.schema)

# Здесь я пробую разными способами добавлять заголовок поля
    self.rec = self.db.newRecord()
    i = 0
    for f in self.db.fieldNames:
        self.rec[i] = f
        i += 1
    self.rec.store()
    self.rec = self.db.newRecord()

def handle_field(self, obj, field):
    if getattr(obj, field.name) is not None:
        # возвращает название колонки
        if self._name:
            key = self.db.write(field.value_to_string(obj))
        else:
            key = field.verbose_name[:10].encode('cp1251').upper() 
        # возвращает значение ячейки
        if getattr(obj, field.name) == str(getattr(obj, field.name)):
            self.rec[key] = getattr(obj, field.name).encode('cp1251')
        else:
            self.rec[key] = getattr(obj, field.name)

def end_object(self, obj):
    self.rec.store()

def end_serialization(self):
    pass
```

Код работает, но в таблице нет заголовков, только данные. Может, кто-нибудь знает способ добавить заголовок или где можно посмотреть подробную документацию по dbfpy. Другие модули я тоже рассматриваю, если по ним есть подробная документация на английском или русском. Python 2.7, dbfpy 2.3.1, открываю результат с помощью OpenOffice.

Comment: Могу добавить, что в консоль корректно выводится список self.db.fieldNames (6 шт.), а если открыть результат.dbf блокнотом, то перед данными имеется большой массив символов NUL (226 символов).

Comment: Найдите в интернете описание формата dbf и сделайте сделайте свой экспорт. Формат относительно простой. Просто удивительно как библиотекописатели могут ошибаться, всё за них переделывать приходится. Если в виндовсе дело проиходит, то можно подключить dbf через odbc (только 32бит). Есть в питоне odbc?

Comment: К сожалению, моих знаний вчерашнего студента пока не хватает для написания своего модуля экспорта. И автор dbfpy не ошибся, просто его модуль практически не документирован, пришлось глубоко копать в коде, чтобы решить проблему.

Comment: Какая там сложность? Текстовый файл с заголовком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во всех примерах после добавления всех записей рекомендуют закрывать базу данных командой self.db.close().

В моём случае это не подходит, потому что файл сохраняется в I/O потоке self.stream, с которым в другом модуле продолжается работа, а метод close закрывал этот поток. Поэтому блок end_serialization пропускался. Но в тексте dbfpy метод close имеет важное значение, поэтому используем важную часть, не закрывая файл. Теперь наш end_serialization выглядит так:

```
def end_serialization(self):
    pass
    self.db.flush()
```